# Add string to Watch Kit App from iOS parent app on Watch App Install

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-4

I am using watchOS 4 and am wondering how I can have some default values sent to the Watch App when it gets installed? These values need to come from the iOS parent app.

I don't see a way of doing this on installation, is there?

Comment: Do you mean you want to transfer data generated in __runtime__ from your iOS app to your watchOS app __while the app installs__? It's not possible to run any custom code during a watchOS app's installation.

Comment: Yes. I mean have values available when the watch app runs for the first time. Similar to NSUserDefaults shared, which I realize isn't possible anymore.

Comment: Then what you are asking for is not possible at all. Even though if what you are trying to achieve could be achieved by simply sharing `UserDefaults`, then you aren't truly looking for an installation time solution. I don't even see a point in trying to inject data during installation. You can easily detect first launch of your app and simply grab the necessary data from your iOS app runtime during the first launch of the watchOS app.

Comment: @DávidPásztor How would I detect first launch? And, what if the parent device is out of range?

Comment: You can simply create a boolean to one of your classes called `firstLaunch` that is `true` by default and you toogle it to `false` during app launch, then save it to `UserDefaults` and it won't be toggled again since its value will aready be `false`. If your parent device is out of range how would you dynamically transfer data from it even if you could inject code during installation?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Think of the Series 3 watch. It has LTE. Our app connects to an API do I need the access token from the parent app that has already authenticated.

Comment: Sure, if you're only targeting the Series 3 watch, then you could do use an API call in case the watch has a network and it's not connected to the phone. But in reality Series 3 is only a small portion of all Apple Watches out on the market, so you still need a working alternative for the older devices.

Comment: I would use the WatchConnectivity framework, and transfer the token when the IOS app authenticates to the watch immediately.  The ApplicationContext transfer will make it available for when the watch app is first used.  The watch app can have first run flag/flags as David mentions.